Java/Kotlin Flyway + MyBatis + HikariCP connection leak
I am developing some pure Kotlin application. In my aplication I need to access Database.
My curretn stack for it

mybatis version = "3.5.16"
flyway version = "10.19.0"
hikari version = "6.0.0"

So for development i am using Intellij Idea. This is important. After some time of development i have an error in my database - to many connection. I think it is becouse of debug and termination of the process. I think it prevents to close connection gently.
I didn't find any root cause. When i do it manually for many times i didn't noticed that a connection is leaked (show processlist; is empty)
Here is code I do it at start of the application:
       
class DB(props: AppProperties) { 
    private val hikariSource: HikariDataSource
    private var batisSessionFactory: SqlSessionFactory

    // Constructor
    init {
         // HikariCP
        hikariSource: HikariDataSource = HikariDataSource()
        hikariSource.jdbcUrl = props.databaseUrl
        hikariSource.username = props.databaseUser
        hikariSource.password = props.databasePass
        hikariSource.maximumPoolSize = 5
        hikariSource.isAutoCommit = true

        // Flyway
        val config = Flyway
            .configure()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .baselineOnMigrate(true)

        val flyway = Flyway(config)
        flyway.migrate()

        // MyBatis
         batisSessionFactory = createSqlSessionFactory(hikariSource).apply {
            configuration.addMapper(UserDao::class.java)
        }
    }

    fun <T> withUserDao(autoCommit: Boolean = true, block: UserDao.() -> T) : T {
        return batisSessionFactory.openSession(autoCommit).use {
            val userDao = it.getMapper(UserDao::class.java)
            block(userDao)
        }
    }

    private fun createSqlSessionFactory(dataSource: DataSource): SqlSessionFactory {
        val configuration = Configuration()

        // Pass your custom DataSource to the environment
        val environment = org.apache.ibatis.mapping.Environment(
            props.environment,
            org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory(),
            dataSource
        )
        configuration.environment = environment
        return SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration)
    }
}

Thats it. This simple code makes some connection leaks. And I am not sure who is responsible for this leak. Hikari? Flyway? MyBatis?
for Java developers about function withUserDao()

open a batis session like try-with-resources java style
inside try block get mapper for UserDao and pass it to lambda outer
after any work with user dao - close the batis session


What does 'do it manually' mean? What is the opposite that is causing the leak?
A connection pool doesn't/shouldn't create connections more than 5 (=max pool size) even if the app code leaks connections.
So, if the DB complains about 'too many connections', it usually means that there are multiple active connection pools.
It might happen if the IDE 'reloads' the app without cleaning up its resources correctly, for example.
This article (and its sequel) might help if you haven't read it.

Yes. It is also my assumption - when I develop I start and terminate application a lot of times. And some times when everything is stopped. I see that MySQL server has active connections. Manually - I mean run and terminate a lot of times just to find the reason

Author of HikariCP here. Make sure the computer running MySQL, whether local or remote, has keepAlive enabled. This should allow MySQL to (hopefully) recognize when connections have been abandoned. See https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Setting-OS-TCP-Keepalive.

@brettw Thanks for comment. Checked. Seems it was not enabled. Need some time for tests, will notify you. Also. Do I need to use some options like hikariSource.keepaliveTime = 30000 ?

@brettw Seems it works. Checked config MySQL and changed config for OS. Seems now it works fine, For 1 day development I didn't reproduce this issue
